# EJB Transaction does not starts pojo transaction

Tags: java, spring, ejb-3.0

I'm trying to have the EJB transaction propagated to a Pojo annotated with  @Transactional.

Both in the EJB and in the Pojo the transactions works but they don't seem to talk to each other.

I cant see the Pojo's transaction active in the EJB.

My EJB is like:

```
@Stateless(name = "MyEJB", mappedName = "MyEJB")
@Remote(IMyEjb.class)
@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
public class MyEJBBean implements IMyEjb {

@Autowired
private MyService myService;

@Resource
TransactionSynchronizationRegistry tsr;

@Override
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public Customer doMyStuff(String username) throws BusinessException{
      Customer customer = myService.doMyStuff(username);
    System.out.println("Pojo transaction:" + TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());
    System.out.println("Ejb transaction:" + tsr.getTransactionStatus());  
    customer = myService.doMyStuff(username);

    return customer;       

}
}
```

The Pojo implementation follows:

```
@Component
public class MyService {

@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRED)
public Customer doMyStuff(String username){
  System.out.println("Pojo transaction in object:" + TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive());

   return new Customer();

}
}
```

I've tryied many Spring configurations actually I'm using the following:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
   xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:orcl="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/orcl"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/orcl 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/orcl/spring-data-orcl-1.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.3.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.ericsson.noc"/>
<context:annotation-config />
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.ericsson.noc" />    

<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/OracleDS"
        expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

 <bean id="transactionManager" 
      class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
   <property name="transactionManagerName" value="java:appserver/TransactionManager"/>
   <property name="userTransactionName" value="java:comp/UserTransaction"/>
</bean>             

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" 
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
      p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
      p:persistenceUnitName="oracle">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
</bean>


<context:load-time-weaver/>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"  mode="aspectj" />    
 <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
 </beans>
```

If i run the code I got the folowing output:
Pojo transaction:false
Ejb transaction:0
Pojo transaction in object:true.
Ejb transaction:0 mean that it's active.
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/constant-values.html#javax.transaction.Status.STATUS_ACTIVE

Now I'm expecting a wrong result or what should I do to have the pojo transaction open in the ejb.

Comment: While looking at the log statements you mentioned above I am not sure what makes you say this "I cant see the Pojo's transaction active in the EJB." ?

Comment: If I call TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive() in the EJB it return false... I had to move all the business code in the Pojo to have a valid transaction for the JPA repositories... I would expect that Spring Joins the EJB transaction being  JTA.. have you succeded in that? thanks

Comment: I have not used it myself. However while doing some research on this I found this - https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-4249 . Could be useful to you.

Comment: thanks a lot.. but it's not that the case. In my situazion on the Spring side the transaction is properly started.. and also on the EJB side but they are not joined.

Answer (score 0):

Change `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)` to `@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` or to `@javax.transaction.Transactional(javax.transaction.Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)`